# JMSCC0005: The specified value '0' is not allowed for 'JMSDeliveryMode'. The given value is not allowed for the property specified

Tags: java, ibm-mq, spring-jms

while sending message to queue we are getting this exception after upgrading our IBM mq server from 7.5 to 9.3 version , I have also updated ibm mq dependencies from 7.x version to 9.x version.

it was working fine with old version of IBM mq.

ivy.xml dependencies:

Old dependencies:


`

total error :

```
 Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Failed to send JMS message to queue://QueueManger/MYQUEUE after 3 tries.
    at com.west.judicial.common.jms.writer.JmsSender.send(JmsSender.java:130) \~\[CommonServiceJmsUtil-2022.01.1.jar:?\]
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException: Uncategorized exception occurred during JMS processing; nested exception is com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSCC0005: The specified value '0' is not allowed for 'JMSDeliveryMode'.
The given value is not allowed for the property specified.
Change the value to a value that is supported for the property.
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.convertJmsAccessException(JmsUtils.java:316) \~\[spring-jms-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE\]
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.convertJmsAccessException(JmsAccessor.java:169) \~\[spring-jms-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE\]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:487) \~\[spring-jms-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE\]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:559) \~\[spring-jms-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE\]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.convertAndSend(JmsTemplate.java:648) \~\[spring-jms-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE\]
    at com.west.judicial.common.jms.writer.JmsSender.send(JmsSender.java:120) \~\[CommonServiceJmsUtil-2022.01.1.jar:?\]
    ... 26 more
\*\*Caused by: com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSCC0005: The specified value '0' is not allowed for 'JMSDeliveryMode'.\*\*
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor130.newInstance(Unknown Source) \~\[?:?\]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) \~\[?:1.8.0_212\]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) \~\[?:1.8.0_212\]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se.NLSServices.createException(NLSServices.java:334) \~\[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.3.2.1.jar:9.3.2.1 - p932-001-230405\]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.nls.NLSServices.createException(NLSServices.java:226) \~\[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.3.2.1.jar:9.3.2.1 - p932-001-230405\]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsErrorUtils.createException(JmsErrorUtils.java:126) \~\[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.3.2.1.jar:9.3.2.1 - p932-001-230405\]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsMessageImpl.setJMSDeliveryMode(JmsMessageImpl.java:1092) \~\[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.3.2.1.jar:9.3.2.1 - p932-001-230405\]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsMessageImpl.copyMessageState(JmsMessageImpl.java:601) \~\[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.3.2.1.jar:9.3.2.1 - p932-001-230405\]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsMessageImpl.\(JmsMessageImpl.java:572) \~\[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.3.2.1.jar:9.3.2.1 - p932-001-230405\]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsTextMessageImpl.\(JmsTextMessageImpl.java:142) \~\[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.3.2.1.jar:9.3.2.1 - p932-001-230405\]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsMessageImpl.messageToJmsMessageImpl(JmsMessageImpl.java:2514) \~\[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.3.2.1.jar:9.3.2.1 - p932-001-230405\]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsMessageProducerImpl.sendMessage(JmsMessageProducerImpl.java:785) \~\[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.3.2.1.jar:9.3.2.1 - p932-001-230405\]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsMessageProducerImpl.synchronousSendInternal(JmsMessageProducerImpl.java:2055) \~\[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.3.2.1.jar:9.3.2.1 - p932-001-230405\]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsMessageProducerImpl.sendInternal(JmsMessageProducerImpl.java:1993) \~\[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.3.2.1.jar:9.3.2.1 - p932-001-230405\]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsMessageProducerImpl.send(JmsMessageProducerImpl.java:1573) \~\[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.3.2.1.jar:9.3.2.1 - p932-001-230405\]
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQMessageProducer.send(MQMessageProducer.java:321) \~\[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.3.2.1.jar:9.3.2.1 - p932-001-230405\]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.doSend(JmsTemplate.java:623) \~\[spring-jms-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE\]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.doSend(JmsTemplate.java:597) \~\[spring-jms-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE\]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate$3.doInJms(JmsTemplate.java:562) \~\[spring-jms-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE\]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:484) \~\[spring-jms-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE\]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:559) \~\[spring-jms-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE\]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.convertAndSend(JmsTemplate.java:648) \~\[spring-jms-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE\]
    at com.west.judicial.common.jms.writer.JmsSender.send(JmsSender.java:120)
```

if I set jmsDeliveryMode explicitly in the code it will work but I wanted to know why it is not working with new version of IBM mq?

Comment: new dependecies:
ivy.xml :
<dependency org="com.ibm.mq" name="com.ibm.mq.allclient" rev="9.3.2.1"/>                                                       old  dependecies: <dependency org="com.ibm" name="com.ibm.mq"     rev="7.0.1.7" /> 
<dependency org="com.ibm" name="com.ibm.mqjms"  rev="7.0.1.7" /> 
<dependency org="com.ibm" name="com.ibm.mq.pcf" rev="7.0.1.7" />